# What's causing "error executing query: connection timed out" in my ColdFUsion/MySql?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I get this somewhat frequent error and I don't know what's causing the trouble. My site and MySQL database are hosted at hosting.com.

Can someone help me decode this? I want to understand what this error is desperately trying to tell me so I can fix the problem.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** java.net.ConnectException MESSAGE: Connection timed out: connect STACKTRACE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:469) at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:366) at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:209) at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:173) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:267) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2739) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1553) at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266) at coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.pool.JDBCPool.createPhysicalConnection(JDBCPool.java:589) at coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.pool.ConnectionRunner$RunnableConnection.run(ConnectionRunner.java:67) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) ** END NESTED EXCEPTION ** Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago. at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2814) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1553) at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266) at coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.pool.JDBCPool.createPhysicalConnection(JDBCPool.java:589) at coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.pool.ConnectionRunner$RunnableConnection.run(ConnectionRunner.java:67) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple. It seems their database is on a remote machine and as the exception says: there is a network failure preventing the CF application talking to the database.

You need to get hosting.com support on the case. Provide the exception details and the times they occurred.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Ciaran. I'm on my way to chat with them now. I was just notified of the same error on another page.